# Unwanted mapped drive creation from unknown source

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, windows-domain, network-drive, mapped-drive

I'm stuck in a situation where I have a network drive being mapped when I log in that I don't want. The drive (X:) is a copy of another drive I do want (W:) which is also mapping. I have no need for it to be mapped twice. I disconnect X: and it is remapped at next login. I have checked the many group policies thoroughly on the server and can find nothing that would be causing X: to be mapped. I have also checked any login scripts I can find to see if net use is being used in a .bat file but still, nothing.

Are there any client logs that show what is causing the network drives to map? How do I further troubleshoot this? I do have a group policy in place to map X to a different drive location for specific users which works fine, and I need that functionality to remain, so I am unable to create a disconnect .bat for X: on login because the legitimate X: drive for other users will be affected. Thanks.

Comment: If you log in as another domain user, does it get mapped the same way?  If you log on as a local user, does it get mapped?  Did you use GPResult when trying to resolve how it's getting added?

Comment: It happens as other domain users on other machines too. It does not happen when logging in locally. GPResult /r shows applied GP's, none of which appear to contain the rouge mapping

Comment: It's defiantly a domain policy that's causing it then.  Check startup/login scripts that are being run, as they may be mapping the drive (which wont' be obvious in GPResult).

Comment: *Definitely, not Defiantly. :)

Comment: I would usually agree, but myself and my colleague have looked already, there is nothing in the logon scripts to cause this. Can you point me to any logs that may shed light on issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the GPO making changes to the W drive was not running with 'Run in logged on users security context' and did not have permission to amend any W drive that was created manually by a user. It therefore decided on it's own accord to create the W mapping using the letter X. I have no idea why Microsoft decided this was a good idea rather than throwing a warning up in event viewer, but after adding this setting and creating a delete map for X, it all works properly now.